# I need a francophone book of mathematics of 1st and 2nd year of university

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability-theory, statistics, reference-request

I am from Algeria and I'm on 2nd year on a preparatory class for engineers. We took calculus and algebra and statistics/probabilities in the 1st year, and now we study calculus and "analyse numérique". I was always searching for books or any source that covers our program with full proofs but I didn't find any. They are just explaining courses without proving them. Could you help me? We study with the french language here but I would be happy if an English book does contain what I want.

Comment: Why not ask your instructor?